# How can I implement an interface with a property of type IEnumerable<IA> and override with a type that implements the interface of the type?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to do the following or similar:

```
public interface IDataTable
{
  IEnumerable<IColumnDefinition> Columns
}
```

Implement that interface in a base class as follows:

```
public class DataTableBase : IDataTable
{
  public virtual IEnumerable<IColumnDefinition> Columns { get; set; }
}
```

Then inherit from that base class but override or hide the virtual type

```
public class AngularDataTable : DataTableBase
{
  public override IEnumerable<IAngularColumnDefinition> Columns { get; set; }
}
```

The IAngularColumnDefinition implements the IColumnDefinition interface and adds a few properties that are specific to the Angular DataTable.

```
public interface IAngularColumnDefinition : IColumnDefinition
{
  string AdditionalProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I keep getting compile error because IColumnDefinition can't be implicitly cast to IAngularColumnDefinition.

What is the best way to accomplish my goal? Should I just not add Columns to the base interface and class and instead create and implement in the derived classes?

Comment: Now might be a good time to start reading Eric Lippert's blog - particularly his [most recent post](http://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/)

Comment: maybe Explicity property and cast IEnumerable<IAngularColumnDefinition> to IEnumerable<IColumnDefinition> as workaround

Comment: His most recent post doesn't actually answer the question... just present the problem dageniusal is having.

Comment: The short answer is no, you cannot do it the way you're asking in the first half of the question. As for how else to achieve this, hopefully you'll get a full answer explaining it. The generics answer already posted is certainly a way, but it might not be to everyone's taste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about generics?

```
public interface IDataTable
{
    IEnumerable Columns { get; set; }
}

public interface IDataTable<IColumnDef> : IDataTable
{
    IEnumerable<IColumnDef> Columns { get; set; }
}

public class DataTableBase<TColumnDef> : IDataTable<TColumnDef>
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<TColumnDef> Columns { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable IDataTable.Columns
    {
         get { return this.Columns; }
         set { return this.Columns = value.Cast<TColumnDef>() } // possible problem
                       //but f.e. you can forbide setting prop for non-generic version
    }
}

public class DataTableBase :DataTableBase<IColumnDefinition> 
{
}

public class AngularDataTable : DataTableBase<IAngularColumnDefinition>
{
}
```

Of course, there are few drawbacks with that approach, f.e. you cannot do the following assigment:

```
DataTableBase @base = new AngularDataTable(); // compile-time error
DataTableBase<IAngularColumnDefinition> @base = new AngularDataTable(); //that's fine
```

Answer (score 0):

The override keyword won't work if your function has two different signatures, which yours do.

```
public baseClass GetSomething();

public override childClass GetSomething();
```

That code will fail, because the GetSomething functions

You can also not have two functions that differ by return type alone. If you don't override your base method, your child will end up with two `GetSomething` functions, which will be ambiguous if you try and call them.

You have a few options, but none of them are particularly pretty. One option is you can just have your AngularDataTable return IEnumerable and have the code calling the function cast your columns.